# Override a property and make it Translatable in Doctrine Translatable / Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-extensions

I have a mapped-superclass with a string property 'name' which belongs to a bundle (SyliusAssortmentBundle, actually).
I have a class in my bundles that inherits from that mapped-superclass.
I'd like to add Translatable capabilities to my entity by using DoctrineExtensions (Translatable).
Since I cannot redeclare the property 'name' in my mapping, I am trying to override the mapping of that property following this doctrine documentation:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#attribute-override

Inspired by this, I added this to my product.orm.xml file

```
    <attribute-overrides>
        <attribute-override name="name">
            <field name="name" column="name" type="string">
                <gedmo:translatable/>
            </field>
        </attribute-override>
    </attribute-overrides>
```

this doesn't seem to be working. I have added a dummie property (trans_name) to my entity so I am sure that the Translatable Extension is working.

```
    <field name="trans_name" type="string">
        <gedmo:translatable/>
    </field>
```

After persisting with something like:

```
$e->setTranslatableLocale('fr_fr');
$e->setName('name fr');
$e->setTransName('trans name fr');
```

just the 'trans_name' has been saved to 'ext_translations' table.

So. Is it possible to override the mapping and add Translatable?
If so. What am I doing wrong?...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the `@AttributeOverrides`, `@AssociationOverrides`, etc annotations are introduced to override Doctrine's fields and associations. Overriding other annotations (like `@Gedmo\Translatable`) is not supported.

As alternative you could copy/paste the mappings to your own bundle, add the extra ones you need (like `@Gedmo\Translatable`) and load these mappings in stead of the ones from SyliusAssortmentBundle.

Comment: thanks Jasper. That was a bit of wishful thinking to try that I guess :-) I've tried the alternative you point out which I think should work... but still have some issue comming form (I think) the fact that the original bundle uses Doctrine's RTEL. didn't go further researching and solved it creating a couple of custom translatable properties. (btw: not SyliusAssortmentBundle anymore but SyliusVariableProductBundle)

Comment: RTEL shouldn't be a problem, just make sure the XML mapping files from the 3rd party bundle (the ones you copied) are _not_ loaded.

Comment: That is actually one of the saddest, and yet truest replies I have read on Stack Overflow. :(

Answer (score 0):

Suppose problem solved years ago, but I just created pull request in `gedmo/doctrine-extensions` because just bumped to same problem: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/pull/1631